# startAnimation without clicking button

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, layout, android-animation

I am trying to have animation from layout to layout. I tried this code and kept in a method and I was not get executed i.e it is not taking me to another layout

Here is my code

```
private void showNextScreen() {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            R.anim.push_left_in);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            startActivity(new Intent(context, MainLoginSignUpActivity.class));
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in,
                    R.anim.push_left_out);
        }
    });// What to add here "startAnimation(animation);" --> But this shows error how to add it
}
```

Before this i am calling this method from this code

```
context = this;
        new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                showNextScreen();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }
        }.start();
```

Please help to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: you don't start your animation ...

Comment: @njzk2  how to startAnimation... I tried in this way startAnimation(animation); but it shows error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am showing the animation in this way .check out the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcomescreen);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginScreen.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein, R.anim.splashfadeout);
        }
    }, CommonVariables.SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME);
```

}
  }

and here is the animation xml : mainfadein.xml

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1000"/>
```

and splashfadeout.xml

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:zAdjustment="top"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="1000"/>
```

Comment: Whate is "CommonVariables" in the above code. I was not able to get the varaible initialisation of "CommonVariables".SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME in the last line of code

Comment: U can hard code it as 3000 . Thats just a common class where I am storing my static variable